# Get coefficients of symbolic polynomial in Matlab

Tags: matlab, polynomial-math, symbolic-math, binomial-coefficients

I have a Matlab function that returns a polynomial of the form:

```
poly = ax^2 + bx*y + cy^2
```

where a, b, and c are constants, and x and y are symbolic (class `sym`).

I want to get the coefficients of the polynomial in the form `[a b c]`, but I'm running into the following problem. If the function returns `poly = y^2`, then `coeffs(poly) = 1`. I don't want this – I want it to return `[0 0 1]`.

How can I create a function that will give me the coefficients of a symbolic polynomial in the form that I want?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`sym2poly`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/sym2poly.html) if your polynomial is a function of a single variable like your example `y^2`:

```
syms y
p = 2*y^2+3*y+4;
c = sym2poly(p)
```

which returns

```
c =

     2     3     4
```

Use `fliplr(c)` if you really want the coefficients in the other order. If you're going to be working with polynomials it would probably also be a good idea not to create a variable called `poly`, which is the name of a function you might want to use.

If you actually need to handle polynomials in multiple variables, you can use [MuPAD](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/getting-started-with-mupad.html) functions from within Matlab. Here is how you can use MuPAD's [`coeff`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/coeff.html) to get the coefficients in terms of the order of variable they precede (`x` or `y`):

```
syms x y
p = 2*x^2+3*x*y+4*y;
v = symvar(p);
c = eval(feval(symengine,'coeff',p,v))
```

If you want to extract all of the information from the polynomial, the [`poly2list`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/poly2list.html) function is quite helpful:

```
syms x y
p = 2*x^2+3*x*y+4*y;
v = symvar(p);
m = eval(feval(symengine,'poly2list',p,v));
c = m(:,1); % Coefficients
degs = m(:,2:end); % Degree of each variable in each term
```

The polynomial can then be reconstructed via:

```
sum(c.*prod(repmat(v,[size(m,1) 1]).^degs,2))
```

*<sub><sub>By the way, good choice on where you go to school. :-)</sub></sub>*

Comment: Hi @horchler, using Matlab R2019a gives the following error:
`Error using mupadengine/feval (line 195)
Invalid number of arguments.`
The documentation for R2019a indicates that this should work, however (see the link you posted). I'm only able to get it to run the function with `m = eval(feval(symengine,'poly2list',p));` but I am working with a large number of variables and I want a particular order of coefficients. Any thoughts?

Comment: @MattG: looks like the problem may be that `poly2list` is not automatically converting the symbolic array `v` to a string anymore. As a workaround you can manually convert to a string: `vc=char(v);` `m=eval(feval(symengine,'poly2list',p,vc(9:end-2)));`. This may be a bug because MuPAD's `coeff` does not appear to have this issue.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I ended up finding a solution in this Matlab Central question:
https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/370283-how-to-use-poly2list-for-specific-variables

Answer (score 1):

There is also an alternative to this problem. For a given degree, this function returns a polynomial of that degree and its coefficients altogether.

```
 function [polynomial, coefficeint] = makePoly(degree)
 syms x y 
 previous  = 0 ;
 for i=0:degree
     current = expand((x+y)^i);
     previous= current +  previous  ;   
 end
  [~,poly] = coeffs(previous);
 for j= 1:length(poly)
     coefficeint(j) = sym(strcat('a', int2str(j)) );
 end
 polynomial = fliplr(coefficeint)* poly.' ;
 end
```

Hope this helps.